# Update text in button in one opened view after choose something from aonther view in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have one view that is contain some data is reading values from server and when the user click on one button I opened another view as popup view then the user make selection to something from this view then when is clicking on OK button the user must return directly to the previous opened view only with update the text on the clicked button with the selected choice.

I don't know if something like that is possible or not in swift 3, I made everything only I don't know what is the way I can use it to make update only on the text of button without make update for all view after read this value from another view!

Main View:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //read saved username
    let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    Savedusername = prefs.object(forKey: "SavedUsername")as! String


    self.getUserData() 
   //after this I read and display all date from server and it's OK

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I used layout directly to go from first view to another view when click on button.

This is the code of OK clicked button , here I want to read the value of choice variable that is take value in the second view and passing this value to the first view only to update text on the first clicked button

```
 @IBAction func okPressedButton(_ sender: Any) {

    //here how I can passing data without using this line that is make update for all previous view
    //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "first_view", sender: self)

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil )

}
```

Update:

the second view:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
func updateData(data: String)
}

class CalenderPopUpViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var calenderPopUp: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var datePickerView: UIDatePicker!


var delegate:MyProtocol?



var selectedDate:String = ""



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    calenderPopUp.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    calenderPopUp.layer.masksToBounds = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}




@IBAction func selectDatePicker(_ sender: Any) {

    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    var strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePickerView.date)
    self.selectedDate = strDate
    print(selectedDate)


}

@IBAction func okPressedButton(_ sender: Any) {


    self.delegate?.updateData(data: self.selectedDate)

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil )

}

@IBAction func cancelPressedButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil )

}



 }
```

the First class :

```
class UserInfoViewController: UIViewController{
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .


     func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "read_date_from_calender" {
        (segue.destination as! CalenderPopUpViewController).delegate = self
    }
}

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if(receiveddata != "")
    {
        print(receiveddata) // I tried to print received data here but without any result
    }
    }
    }

extension UserInfoViewController: MyProtocol {
func updateData(data: String) {
    self.receiveddata = data
}

}
```

Comment: You need to show us your code that you are trying, without it no one answer your question.

Comment: you can use `Delegate` or `Notification`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you need to use a `protocol`

Write something like this at the top of the class of your modal view/view controllers:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
   func newDataSelected(data: String)
}
```

Then somewhere in your presented view class declare a variable like this

```
var delegate: MyProtocol?
```

Then when you make a selection call the delegate to pass the data back to your presenting view controller:

```
self.delegate?.newDataSelected(data: "someData")
```

When you are presenting the view controller be sure to set the delegate:

```
func present() {
   let modal = ModalViewController()
   modal.delegate = self
   self.present(modal, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Finally make sure that you inherit from the protocol in your presenting view controller

```
extension PresentingViewController: MyProtocol {
   func newDataSelected(data: String) {
       // Do some stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes after searching about the technical meaning of my case I found using of protocol to pass information back to the previous view , but In your answer I didn't understand what is this part can do ?
func present() {
   let modal = ModalViewController()
   modal.delegate = self
   self.present(modal, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

Comment: That function is just an example of what you might be using to present the modal (not the actual classes). Just be sure that wherever your present it you set the delegate on the controller

Comment: I updated my code with using of protocol but I don't know I tried to print received value but without any result !

Comment: What exactly is it doing? Put breakpoints at each step of the process to see where it is failing

Comment: View did appear doesn't get called when a modal view controller is dismissed which could be your problem, try printing the response in the extension or put a breakpoint to see if it is being called.

Comment: Already I tried to print result through extension but it didn't give anything I tried also to put breakpoint in the same line but didn't give anything! What is the problem in this case

Comment: Like I suggested put a breakpoint at every step of the process from presenting the modal to pressing 'Ok'. Check the delegate is actually being set, there's no more advice I can give

Comment: I tried to put breakpoint in this line at Calenderpopview class and it said the delegate is null
self.delegate?.updateData(data: self.selectedDate)

Comment: That's your problem then. Double check the segue identifier is correct or present with code as I suggested

Comment: The identifier is correct , I tried to remove it and make it again with the same result , my code doesn't contain anything error ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do that.

1. Define your own delegate. Define your own protocol with a sub function `onUserDataChanged`. Override in your MainView and set as delegate to second view. In second view, you will call `self.delegate. onUserDataChanged(data)`
2. Use NotificationCenter to notify the info changes.
3. Use global variable or UserDefault. In second view's button tap handler, save the info as the global variable defined. In MainView's `viewWillAppear`, you will read the info and set to button.